# Change computername

Tags: powershell, ssh

I have this script :

```
$db = import-csv -Path ".\host.csv"
 
$inputID = Read-Host -Prompt "ID?"
 
$entry = $db -match $inputID

Write-Host "IP:" $entry.IP

    $User = "user"
    $Password = "Pass" 
    $Command = 'wmic computersystem where caption="%computername%" rename $inputID'

    $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
    $Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($User, $secpasswd)

Get-SSHTrustedHost | Remove-SSHTrustedHost

$SessionID = New-SSHSession -ComputerName $entry.IP -Credential $Credentials -AcceptKey:$true

Invoke-SSHCommand -Index $sessionid.sessionid -Command $Command
```

All works fine but in this command didn't recognize var $inputID; I cannot use " " for all line because I need " " for "%computername%" and all line is define by

```
$Command = 'wmic computersystem where caption="%computername%" rename $inputID'
```

After that, How can I run this command for all hosts where is in .\hosts.csv ?

Answer (score 0):

solved 1 problem

```
$Command = "wmic computersystem where caption=""%computername%"" rename $inputID"
```